# Value passed for `target` on TypeScript property decorator is undefined

Tags: typescript, decorator, tsc, typescript-decorator

I have code along the lines of the following code:

```
// Following the TS specification, this type of function should be handled
// as a decorator factory, so the returned function is the actual decorator.
function annotate(a = 1, b = 2) {
    // This is the actual decorator
    return function (target: Object, context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext) {
        console.log(typeof(typeof(target)) + " repr. type of target: " + typeof(target))
        console.log("target === undefined: " + (target === undefined))
    }
}

class MyClass {
    @annotate()
    abc: string
}
```

If I understood correctly this code should result in the decorator being called on the `abc` property of `MyClass` with the `target` parameter provided to the decorator function be the `MyClass` prototype, but when running this code, the following is printed in console:

```
string repr. type of target: undefined
target == undefined: true
```

So the value passed by the compiled TS code at runtime for `target` is undefined.
I'm wondering why this is happening and how I could fix it.

I've tried it with a normal decorator for testing purposes, omitting the arguments for now and just using a regular decorator function, but the issue persisted.

Part of my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "Node16",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "target": "ES2022",
      "moduleResolution": "Node16",
      /* more options but they should not have any effect */
    },
    "lib": ["ES2022"]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following lines to my `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions` seems to have fixed the issue:

```json
"strict": false,
"experimentalDecorators": true
```